# How to Simulate a Biased 6-sided Dice using Pymc3?

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3

How do I simulate a 6-side Dice roll using Pymc3? Also, what is I know that different sides of the dice have different distributions?

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way to simulate 1000 rolls of a fair 6-sided die in `PyMC3` is

```
import pymc3 as pm

with pm.Model():
    rolls = pm.DiscreteUniform('rolls', lower=1, upper=6)
    trace = pm.sample(1000)
trace['rolls']  # shows you the result of 1000 rolls
```

Note that this is slower, but equivalent, to just calling `np.random.randint(1, 7, size=1000)`.

For 1000 rolls of an unfair die

```
probs = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1])

with pm.Model():
    rolls = pm.Multinomial('rolls', n=1000, p=probs, shape=6)
    trace = pm.sample(1)
```

Which is again equivalent, but slower, than `np.random.multinomial(1000, pval=probs)`.

The situtation in which you would *want* to use `PyMC3` is if you observe, say, 50 rolls of an unfair die, have some *prior* expectation that it is a fair die, and want to evaluate the posterior of that expectation.  Here's an example of that:

```
observations = np.array([20, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]) # sums up to 50
with pm.Model():
    probs = pm.Dirichlet('probs', a=np.ones(6))  # flat prior
    rolls = pm.Multinomial('rolls', n=np.sum(observations), p=probs, observed=observations)
    trace = pm.sample(1000)
trace['probs']  # posterior samples of how fair the die are
```

You can use the built-in `traceplot` to see how the samples look:

[image: posterior plot]

Note that we correctly work out that one of the sides comes up more often than the others!

Comment: perfect! Thanks again.